# Solving a system of ODE

Tags: differential-equations

I try to solve a system of 5 odes but I get an annoying error:

I use

```
ClearAll
ode1 = y'[x] == -y[x] + xSin[x] + xExp[x];
ode2 = y'[x] == (y[x] (1 - x)/x^2);
ode3 = y'[x] == xy[x]/(x^2 - 2 y^2);
ode4 = 2 xy'[x] == -x^2 y''[x] + y[x];
ode5 = -4 y'[x] == y''[x] - 4 y[x] + xExp[x];
DSolve[{ode1, ode2, ode3, ode4, ode5}, {y[x]}, x]
```

then I am told "DSolve::dvnoarg: The function y appears with no arguments."

Then I add some IC:

```
ClearAll
ode1 = y'[x] == -y[x] + xSin[x] + xExp[x];
ode2 = y'[x] == (y[x] (1 - x)/x^2);
ode3 = y'[x] == xy[x]/(x^2 - 2 y^2);
ode4 = 2 xy'[x] == -x^2 y''[x] + y[x];
ode5 = -4 y'[x] == y''[x] - 4 y[x] + xExp[x];
ic = y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, y''[0] == 1;
DSolve[{ode1, ode2, ode3, ode4, ode5}, {y[x]}, x]
```

and I get

"Syntax::tsntxi: "ic=y[0]==1,y'[0]==0,y''[0]==1;" is incomplete; more input is needed."

I try Nassers correction, and it works out well, but a new strange message appears

```
ode1 = y'[x] == -y[x] + x*Sin[x] + x*Exp[x];
ode2 = y1'[x] == (y1[x] (1 - x)/x^2);
ode3 = y2'[x] == x*y2[x]/(x^2 - 2 y2[x]^2);
ode4 = 2 x*y3'[x] == -x^2*y3''[x] + y3[x];
ode5 = -4 y4'[x] == y4''[x] - 4 y4[x] + x*Exp[x];
DSolve[{ode1, ode2, ode3, ode4, ode5}, {y[x], y1[x], y2[x], y3[x], 
  y4[x]}, x]
```

*Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.*

From here I am not sure where the error lies.

Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: You have many problems. some math, and some syntax., First the math: why do you have different ode's all with same dependent variable and trying to solve them all for one variable? You will get `DSolve::overdet: There are fewer dependent variables than equations, so the system is overdetermined.` now for the syntax part. Need to use `y[x]` and not `y` everywhere. do `y^2` is wrong. It should be `y[x]^2`. Also watch for spaces. Better to use explicit `*`. So `xy[x]` is wrong. it should be `x*y[x]` or `x y[x]`. Same for `xExp[x]`.   I prefer to use `*` myself as it is more clear.

Comment: ... more syntax. You can not write `ic = y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, y''[0] == 1;` it needs to be a list. like this `ic ={ y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, y''[0] == 1};`

Comment: Yes. Or use `y1[x]` and `y2[x]` and `y3[x]` and so on. Just different variables for each ode. If these are coupled ode's, that is ok. Just need to have same number of dependent variables as number of ode's.  I prefer `y1` and `y2` etc.. so that the number helps me know how many odes' there are. But the independent variable should all be the same!  i.e. `x` in your examples.

Comment: You can post your new odes' after the fixes you made. it looks like you still have more problems.

Comment: Posted just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, back to the math issues. Why are you solving these 5 odes at once? You only do that when the odes' are *coupled* which is not the case here. So you can solve them each on its own! This will make life much simpler for you and for Mathematica also.

In addition, some initial conditions lead to singularity, so need to make sure to use the correct ic.

I made up some to get solutions with no errors

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ode1 = y1'[x] == -y1[x] + x*Sin[x] + x*Exp[x];
ode2 = y2'[x] == (y2[x] (1 - x)/x^2);
ode3 = y3'[x] == x*y3[x]/(x^2 - 2 y3[x]^2);
ode4 = 2 x*y4'[x] == -x^2*y4''[x] + y4[x];
ode5 = -4 y5'[x] == y5''[x] - 4 y5[x] + x*Exp[x];

ic1 = y1[0] == 1;
ic2 = y2[1] == 0;
ic3 = y3[1] == 1;
ic4 = {y4[1] == 1, y4'[1] == 1};
ic5 = {y5[0] == 1, y5'[0] == 0};
```

That is all what you need. Now you can solve each ode on its own, since these are not coupled. To solve an ode numerically do like this for each ode

```
 NDSolve[{ode1, ic1}, y1, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To solve it analytically do

```
 DSolve[{ode1, ic1}, y1[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Repeat the above for each ode. Notice the difference. Numerically you need to give the domain of `x` but not with analytical solution.

Comment: Thanks fort this!